# Problems with CakePHP project Upgrade

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP project, initially built using version 1.3. I had saved the files long before and now wanted to deploy the site on my new machine. My new machine runs on PHP 5.4 and hence there were lots of 'Strict Standard' warnings.

I, then downloaded CakePHP Version 2.0 and replaced it with my old 'cake' folder. After that, I ran the 'Update all' command. I got a succesfully updated message. However, I still had to manually change the names of few folders (from config to Config etc.) and specify a path for the bootstrap.php in the app/webroot/index.php

I have managed to get past all the errors, but one, that says "Fatal error: Class 'Dispatcher' not found in /path/to/app/webroot/index.php" on line 82. Is this some path specific error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to manually replace the following:

- app/index.php
- app/webroot/index.php
- app/webroot/test.php
- Any .htaccess file
- Any other core files in the app folder, like cake.generic.css

Comment: Thanks Dunhamzzz! I'm working on it. Once done, I shall come here with the updates.

Comment: @gentrobot you're welcome, there may be other files, like bootstrap.php, config.php etc. Just be sure to also port any changes you made. Should mostly be backwards compatible though

Comment: Your solution worked. My project is still not running, but this time there are issues with the custom classes written inside the app/vendors/ directory. So, I shall debug and fix them. Thanks a lot :)